# Why do we need to equation of state (EOS) equation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, equations-of-motion

I cannot understand why we need the equation of state of star for the numerical solution of TOV equation. In fact, I do not know how EOS equation helps with solving TOV equation. How is EOS  equation used in the numerical solution of TOV equation?

Answer (score 0):

The TOV equation deals with pressure as a function of radius for a gravitating system in hydrostatic equilibrium. It says nothing about the exact manner in which the density of the matter in the system changes in response to those pressures. For a solution to TOV you need an additional equation that relates the density of a matter element to the radius position occupied by that element. That additional equation is the *equation of state* for the matter itself.

Comment: Thank a lot, I want to use the following  polytrope EOS for neutron star.what is the value of 'n'?ρ=KP^(n/(n+1))

Comment: I do not know. -NN